Issue with MTU 9000 Configuration: Jumbo Frames Not Working
Problem Description
I'm experiencing issues with configuring jumbo frames (MTU 9000) on my network. When I set all relevant interfaces to an MTU of 9000, connectivity fails for larger packet sizes. However, when I revert everything back to MTU 1500, the network functions correctly without any issues. Here's a detailed description of my network setup and the troubleshooting steps I've taken so far.
Network Setup

TrueNAS Servers:

Server 1: A TrueNAS server running as a Proxmox VM. Connected to the Proxmox bridge below (vmbr2)
Server 2: A physical TrueNAS server with its LAN directly connected to the eno3 interface of the Proxmox server.


VyOS Router: A VyOS router with the LAN interface (eth1) set to MTU 9000, and the WAN interface (eth0) set to MTU 1500.
Proxmox Server: The physical interface (eno3), and the bridge (vmbr2) connected to VyOS are set to MTU 9000.

Configuration
VyOS Router Configuration:
ip link show eth1
ip link show eth0

Proxmox Interface Configuration:
cat /etc/network/interfaces

TrueNAS Interface Configuration:
ifconfig enp6s19 | grep mtu

Troubleshooting Steps

Verified MTU Settings: Confirmed that all interfaces (TrueNAS, VyOS, Proxmox) are set to MTU 9000.
Ping Tests:

ping -s 1472 -M do 192.168.10.14 works (equivalent to MTU 1500).
Higher MTU sizes (e.g., ping -s 1972 -M do 192.168.10.14) fail.


tcpdump Analysis: Captured packets on VyOS and TrueNAS to check for fragmentation or dropped packets.
Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD): Ensured PMTUD is enabled and not blocked by firewall rules.

Observations

MTU 9000: Connectivity fails with larger packet sizes. Pings with sizes above 1472 bytes do not succeed.
MTU 1500: Everything works perfectly. All pings succeed, and network performance is as expected.

Request for Help
I'm looking for guidance on the following points:

MTU Configuration: Are there any specific configurations or settings that I might have missed for enabling jumbo frames?
Intermediate Devices: Any checks I should perform on the Proxmox bridge or VyOS router to ensure they support and correctly handle jumbo frames?
Network Path: How to effectively diagnose and resolve the issue preventing MTU 9000 from working while MTU 1500 works?

Additional Information

TrueNAS Servers:

Server 1: Proxmox VM with MTU 9000.
Server 2: Physical machine with LAN directly connected to eno3 of Proxmox.


VyOS Router:

eth1 set to MTU 9000 (LAN).
eth0 set to MTU 1500 (WAN).


Proxmox Server:

eno3 and vmbr2 are set to MTU 9000.


Direct Connections: TrueNAS servers are connected to VyOS via Proxmox without any intermediate switches.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
